# minimum spanning tree out of adjacency matrix

Tags: java, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a problem that I am really struggling with.  I have a set of points with weighed edges and I need to create a minimum spanning tree to find the shortest amount of edges needed.  I need to do it in java.  Right now I have it creating an adjacency matrix and thats the point im stuck.  I really have no idea where to go next.  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Here's a hint - write some code and post it.  We don't do homework.  You'll get a better response if you put in some effort and ask specific questions.  Also, mark this as homework.  And read this: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @debracey, what are you talking about? Dijkstra is a shortest path, the OP wants a minimum spanning tree, as in Prim or Kruskal algorithms.

Comment: @debracey: I don't think Dijkstra's algorithm can be used to find a minimum spanning tree. It can be used to find the shortest path between two nodes, but that's it. Perhaps you're thinking of Kruskal's algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on Kruskal and Prim algorithms,
I really like Prim because it is very simple to implement and understand: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm

About your question, what do next (Resumed Prim's algorithm):
 Choose one random vertex and get the edge with smaller cost, insert it into your MST.
 While you do not have all vertex at your MST:
   Choose the edge with smaller cost frm the edges of your MST and insert it at your MST.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find a minimum spanning tree, you will always have the same number of edges, the weights will just be different. The method that I recommend using to solve this problem is Prim's algorithm. It works best when you have distinct weighted edges. Even though someone else has discussed it as a possibility, I will explain it in full here to solve the minimum spanning tree problem with an undirected, connected graph.

The first step to Prim's is starting with any vertex V and add it to a (currently) empty set of vertices called "Discovered". From there, you will look at all of the edges that are adjacent to V (using your adjacency matrix) and are connected to vertices that are not in "Discovered" (using your Discovered set), and add them to a minimum heap structure. The heap will allow you to take the minimum edge and add it to a new tree structure. The other end of that edge is your next new starting vertex. Repeat this process until you have your minimum spanning tree.

Comment: Please elaborate your choice of algorithm. Does it support negative weights? Is it the most efficient for (strictly) positive weights?